# FTP Rush modo seguro

Tags: html

Estou aqui com um problema ao utilizar o FTPRush.
no site que foi criado existe um modo seguro e outro não seguro.

Eu atualmente para entrar utilizo o protocol "SSH FTP"

Tentei entrar de outra forma e não consigo com os mesmos dados.

Necessito de tentar entrar de outra forma porque existe uma pasta que não consigo alterar os dados e com o protocol SSH FTP não funciona.

Qualquer dica pode ajudar.

Em vez de me aparecer PDF'S e um titulo aparece-me assim.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]